# parse error near `]]' for seemingly valid zsh condition

Tags: autocomplete, zsh

I just published a new [zsh tab completion script for Gradle](https://github.com/eriwen/gradle-completion/blob/master/_gradle) but got a puzzler of an issue I hope is just a simple error on my part.

A bug reporter says he's getting "_gradle:14: parse error near `]]'" when trying to invoke completion on zsh 5.0.5 on SUSE, but this code works fine for me on zsh 5.0.8 on macOS and Ubuntu Yakkety.

Can you see anything here that would cause a script parse error?

```
_gradle_caching_policy() {
   [[ ! $(find $1 -mmin -$cache_ttl_mins 2>/dev/null) ]]                                                                                                                                                                                
}
```

Here's the [full issue](https://github.com/eriwen/gradle-completion/issues/4) and another link to the [completion script](https://github.com/eriwen/gradle-completion/blob/master/_gradle). Guidance would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to be a (relatively) recently fixed bug, as it can be reproduced in `zsh` 5.0.5 with something as simple as

```
foo () { [[ bar ]] }
```

which does, however, work in `zsh` 5.2.

---

Update: rereading the question and seeing that it appears to be fixed in 5.0.8 as well, I would just tell the reporter that he needs to upgrade to a version of `zsh` where this parsing bug is fixed. The bug is not in your script.

Comment: Thanks very much for the response. I've asked the contributor to upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

This must be due to unexpected values of `$1` or `$cache_ttl_mins`.

You could circumvent the call to `find` and implement the check analog to other `policy_checks`

```
_gradle_caching_policy() {
    local -a oldp
    oldp=( "$1"(Nmm+${cache_ttl_mins}) )
    (( $#oldp ))
}
```

See if this raises an error, too -- it should behave the same.

Comment: `$1` and `$cache_ttl_mins` aren't expanded at the time the parse error occurs.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error, are you sure the parse error isn't happening in a subshell after expansion of the variables?